how to convert artifact-id to pascal case in maven archetype?
I created a custom Maven archetype and want it to generate Java classes with a prefix in their names when a project is created. The prefix should be the artifact ID in Pascal case. For example, if the artifact ID is sms-api, the generated class should be named SmsApiConfig.java.

Generally, it would make more sense to use a (sub-)package for this purpose instead of putting a fixed String into every class name.

no wanna use different class name (for prevent to create bean with same name)
